# Как вызвать дочерний элемент в цикле simple html dom

Tags: html, парсер

Подскажите кто знаком с simple html dom не могу понят как вызвать дочерний элемент код:

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
        $data = file_get_html('http://topvideo.tj');
          foreach($data->find('.main > li') as $a){
            echo $a.'<br />';
          }
    }
```

в переменой `$data` есть такая структура:

```
    <ul class="main">
            <li><a title="Ролики из категории Юмор" href="/humor/">Юмор</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a title="Ролики из категории Аудио" href="/prank/">Пранки и розыгрыши</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
<li><a title="Ролики из категории Мультфильмы" href="/animation/">Мультфильмы</a>           
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a title="Ролики из категории Мультфильмы" href="/animation/">Детские</a></li>
                <li><a title="Ролики из категории Мультфильмы" href="/cartoons/">Взрослые</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Так как мне вызвать первые `<a>` теги

Comment: Что мешает написать `$data->find('.main > li  > a')` ?

Comment: выводится вместе с тегом `<a>` класса  `sub` а мне нужно именно первый тег `<a>` вызвать.

Comment: Что-то вы врете... он берет `a` непосредственного потомка `li` который является непосредственным потомком `.main`.... вы проверяли или так просто сказали наобум? ......... для наглядности https://jsfiddle.net/yyvvfgg4/

Comment: я проверял берется все `a` в `.main`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите работать с `DOM`, то лучше всего для этого подойдет `JavaScript`.

`HTML`:

```
<ul>
  <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
```

`JS`:

```
document.getElementById("myLI").parentNode.nodeName;
```

Пример: [W3Fiddle](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_parentnode)

Comment: А ничего что у ТС - `PHP` и как бы `JS` крут не был - это не про него вопрос?

Comment: Вы вообще знаете что такое simple html dom?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось с помощью метода `children()`:

```
$items = $data->find('ul.main', 0)->children(); //получаем только дочерние элементы <li>
foreach ($items as $item) { // перебираем элементы <li>
    foreach ($item->children() as $itemChild) //перебираем элементы внутри <li> => [<a>,<ul>]
    if ($itemChild->tag == 'a') { //проверяем является ли элемент ссылкой
        echo $itemChild . '<br />';
    }
}
```